# Closed geodesics and eigenvalues in a non-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be an undirected graph the degree of whose $n$ vertices is $\leq D$ without necessarily being constant. Say we have bounds of type $\leq \gamma^{2 k}$ for the number of closed geodesics of length $2 k$ for any large $k$, for some $\gamma$. Can we bound the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix $A$ of $\Gamma$?

(If the degree were constant, this would be easy, via the Ihara zeta function and/or Hashimoto's operator. When the degree is non-constant, the relation between the Ihara zeta function, on the one hand, and the eigenvalues of $A$, on the other, is less clean.)

If it helps, you can assume $\gamma$ is of size $O(\sqrt{D})$.

Comment: Perron-Frobenius?

Comment: Is that enough? If we had a bound on the number of closed walks of length 2k, the problem would be easy (you wouldn't need Perron-Frobenius). What we are actually given is a bound on the number of closed geodesics, i.e., closed, non-backtracking walks.

Comment: Alternatively: you can use Perron-Frobenius to bound the eigenvalues of Hashimito's edge-adjacency operator, but how do you go from there to the eigenvalues of A when the degree is non-constant?

Comment: I thought that the way to prove that the largest eigenvalue is unique also gives an upper bound.

Comment: Again : an upper bound on what? On the largest eigenvalue of the Hashimoto operator? Sure.

Comment: I do not know what Hashimoto operator is. I was talking  about the adjacency matrix and its largest eigenvalue assuming that the graph is  connected.

Comment: Well, if you know the number of *closed walks* of length $2 k$ for some $k$, then that gives you an upper bound on the largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix almost immediately, without needing to go through Perron-Frobenius. The eigenvalues of $A^{2 k}$ are all non-negative. (That is still the case if you deal not with the adjacency matrix $A$, but with other, related symmetric operators.)

Comment: For the definition of Hashimoto's edge-adjacency operator, see, e.g., http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/EMIS/journals/EJC/Volume_16/PDF/v16i1r84.pdf

Comment: For the sake of correctness the paper you linked to does not have a definition of Hashimoto matrix.

Comment: @dodd See page 4.

Comment: On page 4 the word Hashimoto does not appear.

Comment: "edge adjacency matrix". And it's Hashimoto.

Comment: If the graph is undirected what does it mean that an edge flows into another edge? Def on p 4.

Comment: what is a closed geodesic?

Comment: A non-backtracking closed path that is non-backtracking even if you change the vertex you consider as the origin (i.e., the last edge is not the inverse of the first edge). You can assume that the number of non-backtracking closed paths is also $\geq \gamma^{2 k}$.