# Closed non-backtracking walks and eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix in non-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-walks, spectral-graph-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be an undirected finite graph. Write $M_r$ for the number of non-backtracking closed walks of length $r$ in $\Gamma$, i.e., walks where a step is never
followed by its inverse. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $\Gamma$, and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_N$ its eigenvalues.

If $\Gamma$ is regular of degree $d$, then

$$M_{2 k} = (d-1)^k \sum_{n=1}^N \left(U_{2 k}\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{2 \sqrt{d-1}}\right)
- \frac{1}{d-1} U_{2 k-2}\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{2 \sqrt{d-1}}\right)
\right),$$
where $U_m$ is the $m$th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. For a proof, see, e.g., section 1.4 of the Davidoff-Sarnak-Valette monograph.

In particular, if many ($\geq \epsilon N$, say) of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are large ($\geq \Lambda$, where $\Lambda > 5 \sqrt{d}$, say) then, for $k$ not too small, $M_{2 k}$ is large (in fact, roughly in the order of $\epsilon N\cdot \Lambda^{2 k}$).

Is an expression such as the above possible when $\Gamma$ is not regular? Can we at least obtain the conclusion that, if many of the eigenvalues are large ($\geq \Lambda$, where $\Lambda \ggg \sqrt{D}$, and $D$ is the maximal degree of the vertices of $\Gamma$) then $M_{2 k}$ must be large?

(Related, vaguer question: [Closed geodesics and eigenvalues in a non-regular graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380902/closed-geodesics-and-eigenvalues-in-a-non-regular-graph?noredirect=1#comment967890_380902))

Comment: I do not know what "an expression such as the above possible" means but did you try the graph which is the path of length $n$ or the tree of height 2 with $n+1$ vertices?

Comment: Well, one can't have many large eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ then, since $\textrm{Tr} A^{2 k}$ is not then large: on a tree where every non-root node has $r$ children, the number of closed walks of length $2 k$ is $O(r)^k$.

Comment: Yes, and what I am saying is that neither of those (nor any other tree) contradict the conclusion that I mention at the end. I said that the number of closed walks is $O(r)^k$, not that the number of closed, non-backtracking walks is $O(r)^k$ (though of course it is, being $0$).